# Create and Store Cookies of Onclick Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a cookie to store the text value of **<a>** tags. I know I can use **document.getElementById('whatever')** to extract the text value, but the function should be dynamic, i.e non-specific, by getting the text of the link that the user clicks. Can anyone lend a helping hand and show me how to alter the code for it to work accordingly? Thanks.

```
<a href="" onClick="getOrder">#1234WDF</a>
<a href="" onClick="getOrder">#7643FER</a> 

function getOrder(order){
  createCookie('order', $this.text, 90);
}
```

Comment: `<a ...onClick="getOrder(this)"...>` and that would pass in the clicked link. Plus, this isn't really the "jQuery way" of doing things which would normally be using jquery click handlers in a script tag.

Comment: Beat me to it @JonathanKuhn

Comment: don't work man and i just don't why my question got down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the below code here at StackOverflow, you will see an error message proclaiming that the document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.  So, I respectfully suggest that you see the live demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWGZYE) instead.

```js
function setOrder(name,order){
   document.cookie = name + "=" + order;
   console.log(document.cookie);

}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="setOrder('item1',this.textContent)">#1234WDF</a>
<a href="#" onClick="setOrder('item2',this.textContent)">#7643FER</a>
```

As a reminder about downvoting here at StackOverflow, the official policy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) is as follows:

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter ... an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

My answer matches neither of these conditions and so whoever cast the downvote egregiously maligned the answer, without even extending the courtesy of an explanation.

Comment: Thank man. Not sure why you got down vote. These admin dudes are really terrible. They're taking things way too serious and need to get a life. Anyhow, thanks for the reply. I was able to use your idea by making a change from <a ...onClick="getOrder(this)"...> to <a ...onClick="getOrder(this.textContent)"...> and now it's working.